# Stencil Lifecycle method not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope, lifecycle, stenciljs

I have a query from apollo-client. In my `componentWillLoad()` lifecycle method I can see the query is loading (using `console.log`). But I can not see the data in `render()`. I understand it is due to `Scope` of `componentWillLoad()` function. However I am unable to solve this. I want to have the data as a `State` so that I can render it.

My code is below:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import getApolloClient from '../../apollo-client';


const BOOK_LIST = gql(`
   query Books($id: ID!) {
      bookbook(id: $id)  {
            name
            id
            year
            }
        }
  `);

@Component({
  tag: 'book-details',
  shadow: false,
})
export class BookDetails {
  batches: any;
  error: boolean;

  async componentWillLoad() {
    
    const apolloClient = getApolloClient();
    const bookList = await apolloClient.query({
      query: BOOK_LIST,
      variables:{"id": "230"}
    });
    console.log(activeBatches.data)
    
  }
  
  render() {
  
    return (
      <Host>
      {bookList}
      </Host>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Then store the data in the component state, not in a local variable?

Comment: Can you elaborate more please?

Answer (score 0):

```
 private bookList;

async componentWillLoad() {
    
    const apolloClient = getApolloClient();
    this.bookList = await apolloClient.query({
      query: BOOK_LIST,
      variables:{"id": "230"}
    });
    console.log(activeBatches.data)
    
  }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.